# i want to pass multiple parameter to ajax autocomplete extender

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

is it possible something like this

```
TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender.ServiceMethod = "Getlist(" + TextBox1.Text + "," + TextBox1.Text .Length+ ",size_master,size_id,size_name)";
```

means I want to pass multiple parameter to service.

I saw on internet most post has same copy paste solutions the it suggests to pass argument on key up

my question is if i use set context key then how search parameter will be passed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can pass multiple parameters to the Web method like that.

Parameters are defined in [AutoComplete.js](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AjaxControlToolkit/Scripts/AutoComplete.js), line 677:

```js
var params = { prefixText: this._currentPrefix, count: this._completionSetCount };
```

As you can see, Web method signature expects only 2 (or 3, if you use contextKey) parameters.

You can try to pass multiple parameters to the Web method in a few ways:

1. Change the source code of Ajax Control Tookit in any way you want as long as it is opensource.
2. Try to bind to existing method, say, _onMethodComplete method.
3. As a middle between two previous ways you can replace _tickHandler delegate with your own implemetation.

Answer (score 0):

On Ajax Control add **UseContextKey="true"** and **ContextKey="PARAMETERS"** . If UseContextKey is **true** your Webservice will receive a third parameter: ContextKey

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Columns="50" />
        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
            ID="extNombreAutoComplete" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="Name"
            MinimumPrefixLength="3"
            CompletionInterval="500"
            CompletionSetCount="10"
            UseContextKey="true"
            ContextKey="PUT HERE YOUR PARAMETERS"
            ServiceMethod="SearchName"
            ServicePath="~/utils/AutoCompletar.asmx"
            FirstRowSelected="false" />
```

Your Web service implmentation

```
        [WebMethod()]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    public List<string> SearchName(string prefixText, int count,string contextKey)
    {
        var lista = new List<string>();
        return lista;
    }
```